# Handle pretty http requests for domain and subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The current active urls system is like:

```
http://example.com/dashboard/pages.php
http://example.com/dashboard/page.php?id=10
```

So I want that the same url will be accessible if use:

```
http://example.com/dashboard/pages
http://example.com/dashboard/page/id/10
```

http://example.com/dashboard is pointing to /var/www/html/dashboard

And again when I am using subdomain then I want that the same url will be accessible if I use:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/pages
http://subdomain.example.com/page/id/10
```

Then the active urls system is like :

```
http://subdomain.example.com/pages.php
http://subdomain.example.com/page.php?id=10
```

http://subdomain.example.com is pointing to /var/www/html/dashboard

So the root directory of the domain and subdomain is not the same.

And I want it only for php files. I dont want that it affect the css or js folder structure anyway as I am using relative path.

Can anyone please help that what should be the htaccess content? I am very bad in regular expression handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rewrite rules to the htaccess file in your document root

```
Options -Multiviews FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+dashboard/([^/]+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /dashboard/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+dashboard/([^/]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /dashboard/%1/%2/%3 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dashboard/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)$ /dashboard/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dashboard/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /dashboard/$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Then, to ensure that all your relative links (to stuff like CSS) don't get broken because you've now got a completely different relative URL base, add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/dashboard/" />
```

Or whatever the base should be.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan all the rules work fine for me, do you not have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Can you please code so that I can put the htaccess in the dashboard folder

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan check the error logs, if you want the rules in the "dashboard" folder, you need to change `^dashboard/` to `^` in the regex pattern of the last 2 `RewriteRule`'s.

Comment: Error log saying this after I delete all `dashboard/`: /var/www/html/dashboard/.htaccess: Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan Then add a `+` in front of `FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Can you please help me again as its only working with either subdomain or the main domain. Can you please update the htaccess so that it work with both of domain and subdomain?

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan the rules don't have any bearing on a domain or subdomain, it gets applied no matter what the hostname is. You need to look into your site's setup

Comment: Have you seen my updated question? The root directory of the domain and subdomain is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

**for htaccess:**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# Usually it RewriteBase is just '/', but 
# replace it with your subdirectory path
# For root domain following line
RewriteBase /
# For sub directory following line
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([0-9]+)/?$  $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```

**for make url in php**

```
$re = "/\\.php\\??|=/m";
$str = "http://example.com/dashboard/pages.php\nhttp://example.com/dashboard/page.php?id=10";
$subst = "/";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**output:**

```
http://example.com/dashboard/pages/ 
http://example.com/dashboard/page/id/10
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sI4aB1/1)

Comment: @Sazzad Hossain Khan ok, i have **updated my answer**.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work,

```
substr(strrchr(rtrim($url, '/'), '/'), 1)
```

It will fetch the page number i.e. 10.

Also this will help you,

```
$url='http://example.com/dashboard/page/id/10';

if(preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches))
{
  $end=$matches[1];
}
```

Output for both code will be:

```
10
```

Here is my try with [online tool](http://writecodeonline.com/php/),

[image]

Comment: Ok, then sorry @SazzadHossainKhan I misunderstand your question. But perhaps you already got the answer.

Comment: Ok, I don't have much knowledge in .htaccess codes so can't help you there.